# Run AD queries with Python from a Linux machine

Tags: python, linux, active-directory, ldap

I am developing a `Flask Web-App` that should require `LDAP` authentication.
However, because some users are under different OUs and sometimes the `CN` != `ldap_username` and I want to get the `LDAP destinguishedName` by querying the username.
I know that in `Windows PowerShell` I can use `Get-ADUser username` but I want to do this on `Linux` since I am running my app on a linux machine.

I have tried `python-ldap3` and I can authenticate to the `LDAP server` however, I can't run `AD` Queries (At least I don't know an option to do so) and I have read through the [docs](https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/) but didn't find something that could be of help.

Please note that I want to query on the **Active Directory** by **Username**, like the `Get-ADUser` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would first have to be connected to the `LDAP` server in order to query on it, so firstly you will have to have a user that has permissions to query on the  `AD`.

You say you have succeeded to connect to the `LDAP Server` so I figure you already know the user's `DN` (The one you're using)

In order to connect this code would work:

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection

DN = 'ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com' # This changes depending on your domain architecture
USERNAME = 'cn=user,' + BASE_DN
PASSWORD = 'SuperSecretPass!'
SERVER = 'ldap://server_ip:389' 

ldap_server = Server(SERVER, get_info=ALL)
conn = Connection(ldap_server, user=USERNAME, password=PASSWORD, auto_bind=True)
```

With this you have initialized a connection to the `LDAP Server` and now in order to query for a specific user you can use the function `Connection.search()` and apply a search filter that finds the required user.

You will also have to provide the search with the `base_dn` that should represent under which `OU` the user exists, if you don't know the specific `OU` or the user is under a few sub `OU`s , then you can put the top `OU` (Which is ultimately **Users**) and it should recurse until it finds it.

```
# Assumming base_dn == DN I will just use it as the base dn
username = 'user_to_query'
search_filter = f'(sAMAccountName={username})'

# In your case you only want DN so this option is not needed but this returns the complete summary of the user
attributes = '*' 

query = conn.search(DN, search_filter, attributes=attributes)

# Get the DN from the query_result
if query:
    print(conn.entries[0].entry_dn)
else:
    print("User not found")
```